# XML-VBA SelectNodes grandchildren only (without parent nodes)

Tags: xml, vba, excel, xml-parsing

I am wondering, if it is possible to select all nodes of all grandchildren, without their parent nodes.

```
<shelf>
  <book name="Moby Dick">
     <price>4.50$</price>
  </book>
  <book name="Hamlet">
     <price>5$</price>
  </book>
  <book name="Faust">
     <price>12$</price>
  </book>
</shelf>
```

In this example, I want a list with the prices. My problem is that I need to access them from the "shelf"-axis.

I tried the following code, without success.

```
Set xmlPrices = xmlDoc.SelectNodes("/shelf/book//price")
```

So I want a node list with prices only.

```
<price>4.50$</price>
<price>5$</price>
<price>12$</price>
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: It is not clear what you want to achieve. You say you want a list with the prices, I think `xmlDoc.SelectNodes("/shelf/book//price")` would give you a node list with the `price` elements. Then you show a list of price values like `4.50$`. So what exactly is the problem, extracting the values like `4.50$` from the elements like `<price>4.50$</price>`? The `text` property in the MSXML DOM should allow that.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I want a node list with the `price` elements. I write the prices into an excel table later. But `xmlDoc.SelectNodes("/shelf/book//price")` seems not to works properly. I edited the original post.

Comment: If you use `For Each Price In xmlDoc.SelectNodes("/shelf/book/price") : Store Price.xml here in your table : Next` then I think your code should work.

Comment: Thank you very much! `i = firstrow; 
                    For Each Price In xmlDoc.SelectNodes("/shelf/book/price");
                        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Tabelle1").Cells(i, 1) = Price.Text;
                    i = i + 1;
                    Next Price`

Answer (score 0):

Try XML Linq.  I made code very robust to handle most issues.

```
Imports System.Xml
Imports System.Xml.Linq
Module Module1
    Const FILENAME As String = "c:\temp\test.xml"
    Sub Main()
        Dim doc As XDocument = XDocument.Load(FILENAME)

        Dim prices() As Decimal = doc.Descendants().Where(Function(x) x.Name.LocalName = "price").Select(Function(y) Decimal.Parse(CType(y, String).Replace("$", ""))).ToArray()
    End Sub

End Module
```

Comment: I need some time to test and implement it. Thank you so far.

Answer (score 0):

I think your XPath query is fine - here's a working example:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Test()

    Dim strXml As String
    Dim objXmlParser As New MSXML2.DOMDocument60
    Dim strXPath As String
    Dim intCounter As Integer
    Dim objXmlNodes As IXMLDOMNodeList
    Dim strNodeValue As String

    'sample xml
    strXml = ""
    strXml = strXml & "<shelf>"
    strXml = strXml & "<book name=""Moby Dick""><price>4.50$</price></book>"
    strXml = strXml & "<book name=""Hamlet""><price>5$</price></book>"
    strXml = strXml & "<book name=""Faust""><price>12$</price></book>"
    strXml = strXml & "</shelf>"

    'load to parser
    objXmlParser.LoadXML strXml

    'query document with XPath
    strXPath = "/shelf/book//price"
    Set objXmlNodes = objXmlParser.SelectNodes(strXPath)

    'iterate output nodes and access properties
    For intCounter = 0 To objXmlNodes.Length - 1
        strNodeValue = objXmlNodes.Item(intCounter).Text
        Debug.Print strNodeValue
    Next intCounter

End Sub
```